# How can I show the old value in option fields in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, updates, edit

I want to show the old select value in this select field when I want to edit. How can I show my old value in these fields?
https://github.com/shakibzaman/book-library-laravel
you can show my GitHub repo-

Here is my rules edit page:

```php
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="chap_id">{{ trans('cruds.chapters.title_singular') }}*</label>
    <select name="chap_id" id="chap_id" class="form-control select2">
        @foreach($chapters as $id => $chapter)
            <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $chapter }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @if($errors->has('name'))
        <em class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ $errors->first('name') }}
        </em>
    @endif
    <p class="helper-block">
        {{ trans('cruds.permission.fields.title_helper') }}
    </p>
</div>
```

**editController**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    if (!Gate::allows('users_manage')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $rule = Rule::find($id);
    $chapters = Chapter::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

    return view('admin.rules.edit', compact('rule', 'chapters'));
}
```

Comment: Old you mean from the previous form submission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `old()` function to get the old value of a field. This function requires one input and that is the name of the field: `old('chap_id')`.

You could use this one:

```
@foreach($chapters as $id => $chapter)
    @if(null !== old('chap_id') && old('chap_id') === $id)
        <option value="{{ $id }}" selected>{{ $chapter }}</option>
    @else
        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $chapter }}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Or the shorter one:

```
@foreach($chapters as $id => $chapter)
    <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('chap_id') === $id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $chapter }}</option>
@endforeach
```